# How to access the data of the parent array when using v-for with an array in an array?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My data structure looks like this:

```js
city: [
{
  foo1: 0,
  foo2: "Family",

  districts: [
    {
      bar1: 0,
      bar2: "event1",
    }
  ]
},
```

My v-for looks like this.

```html
<div v-for="district in city.districts" :bar1="district.bar1" :foo="???"></div>
```

How can I pass the `foo1` and `foo2` from the parent array as a prop to the div of the `v-for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your `districts` array is available via `city.districts`, I'd say you can use

```html
<div v-for="district in city.districts"
     :bar1="district.bar1" :foo1="city.foo1" :foo2="city.foo2">
</div>
```

Of course, these values will be the same for each *district* in a city but that looks like what you want.